# Prove $\lim\limits_{x \to \sqrt{3}} \frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{1}{3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove that $$\lim\limits_{x \to \sqrt{3}} \frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{1}{3}$$

I don't know how to get mathematical terms on here so I appologize if there is any slight confusion with the question.

This is a $\delta$, $\,\epsilon$ question.

Comment: The function being continuous in its neighborhood and defined, you just need to evaluate at $x=\sqrt{3}$

Comment: @Evariste  It's "that time of year", and this is probably a $\delta-\varepsilon$ exercise.

Comment: use that $$\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{3}=\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you! Could you please go further though? I am very new to proving limits and I still am not good at completing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show that no matter what tiny number $\varepsilon$ is, you can still pick a tiny $\delta$ so that if $x$ is within $\delta$ of $\sqrt{3}$ then your function will be within $\varepsilon$ of $1/3$.

Scratch work $\varepsilon >\mid 1/x^2 - 1/3 \mid =\mid (3-x^2)/3x^2 \mid =
\mid (\sqrt{3} - x)(\sqrt{3}+x)/3x^2\mid.$

And there inside is the thing we want to make smaller than $\delta$.  I.e., the $\mid \sqrt{3} - x\mid.$  The other factors are annoying, but we know $x$ is getting close to $\sqrt{3}$ at which point those factors are close to $2\sqrt{3}/9$.  So we can assume, say, that $x$ between $1$ and $2$.  Then $\mid (\sqrt{3}+x)/3x^2\mid < (\sqrt{3}+2)/(3\cdot 1^2)< 4/3 <2.$

Now the proof:

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given.  Set $\delta = \min\{\varepsilon/2, 1/10\}.$  Then if $\mid x - \sqrt{3}\mid <\delta$ we know that $1<x<2$ (so the above inequality holds) and $\mid 1/x^2 - 1/3 \mid = \mid (\sqrt{3} - x)(\sqrt{3}+x)/3x^2\mid < \mid(\sqrt{3} - x)2\mid <2\delta =\varepsilon$.  Done.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understood everything up until "x is getting close to radical 3". I understand that x is getting close to that point but how are the other factors close to 2(radical 3)/9? And how would you be able to assume x is between 1 and 2?

Comment: $\sqrt{3}$ is between 1 and 2, so you know that eventually $x$ will get there too.  If you plug $\sqrt{3}$ into the other factors you get $2\sqrt{3}/9$, although it doesn't matter what that constant is, as long as it can be bounded.

Comment: Could you explain how you came to ∣(3+x)/3x2∣<(3+2)/(3⋅12)<4/3<2  further? And how is delta set to 1/10 or epsilon/2?

Comment: Replace $x$ in numerator by 2 (makes it bigger) and replace by $1$ in denominator (makes it also bigger.  Delta is a small as we need, and it's convenient to make it less than $1/10$ (it keeps $x$ between 1 and 2.  We get to pick delta however we like to make the thing work.